# Perl / Undefined value as a HASH reference when running SNMP queries

Tags: perl, snmp, net-snmp, perl-hash

I'm quite new at Perl and have written a script that polls network equipment for sysUptime data. It first queries the database for possible hosts, returns the information stored in the db as an array, then proceeds to poll the host for uptime by `Net::SNMP` for each array element, based on its IP address. The script looks like this (with relevant portions):

```perl
use Net::SNMP;

# Loop through the DB array
while( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    # Dereference into columns
    my ( $hostname, $ip, $vendor, $model, $status, $queue ) = @row;

    # Pad and print
    printf( "%-24s%-18s%-16s%-20s%-16s%-14s", $hostname, $ip, $vendor, $model, $status, $queue );
    # Open the SNMP session
    my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(     -hostname => $ip,
                                                    -community => 'communityname',
                                                    -version => 'v2c',
                                                    -timeout => 5,
                                                    -retries => 0 );
    # Report error and close it the session doesn't open
    if( !defined $session ) { printf "[SESSION ERROR] %s\n", $error; $session->close(); }

    # Get the host uptime. 
    # *** This is the line where Perl fails with the error message. ***
    my $snmp_response = $session->get_request( -varbindlist => [ ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0" ] )->{".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"};

    # If we don't get a response as the var isn't getting defined, report and close
    if( !defined $snmp_response ) {
           printf "[RESPONSE ERROR]: %s\n", $error;
           $session->close();
    # Otherwise print the query result and then close
    } else {
           print $snmp_response;
           $session->close();
    }
}
```

The script works every time for hosts that are reachable (and returns their correct sysUptime response). A typical valid `@row` would look like this:

```
router10.10.10.1CiscoISR4221ProdQ1
```

The script dies at the first unreachable instance with `"Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at script.pl"` and I can't figure out why this is happening. I have used `"-debug => DEBUG_ALL"` in the session, and can see that the host is timing out, and rather than returning the response timeout error, it just dies.

The following output is from `Net::SNMP->session` output when the `-debug => DEBUG_ALL` flag is used.

```
error: [349] Net::SNMP::Dispatcher::_transport_timeout(): No response from remote host "10.10.10.10"
error: [2363] Net::SNMP::__ANON__(): No response from remote host "10.10.10.10"
debug: [517] Net::SNMP::Dispatcher::_event_delete(): deleted [ARRAY(0x2b8bae8)], list is now empty
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at script.pl line 103.
```

It also doesn't change the situation whether I increase the timeout or retry values. I can't get my head around to understand why it works for the working hosts but fails before grasping the definition error.

If I use `Data::Dumper`, it still doesn't output anything for the failed host. For a working host, the Dumper output is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_transport_argv' => [
                                        '-hostname',
                                        '10.10.10.1',
                                        '-timeout',
                                        5,
                                        '-retries',
                                        0
                                      ],
                 '_nonblocking' => 0,
                 '_discovery_queue' => [],
                 '_error' => undef,
                 '_context_name' => undef,
                 '_version' => 1,
                 '_delay' => 0,
                 '_translate' => 255,
                 '_callback' => undef,
                 '_transport' => bless( {
                                          '_dest_name' => '��a�(',
                                          '_socket' => bless( \*Symbol::GEN16, 'IO::Socket' ),
                                          '_sock_name' => '',
                                          '_timeout' => 5,
                                          '_dest_hostname' => '10.10.10.1',
                                          '_max_msg_size' => 1472,
                                          '_sock_hostname' => '',
                                          '_error' => undef,
                                          '_retries' => 0
                                        }, 'Net::SNMP::Transport::IPv4::UDP' ),
                 '_hostname' => '10.10.10.1',
                 '_security' => bless( {
                                         '_error' => undef,
                                         '_community' => 'communityname',
                                         '_version' => 1
                                       }, 'Net::SNMP::Security::Community' ),
                 '_context_engine_id' => undef,
                 '_pdu' => bless( {
                                    '_security' => $VAR1->{'_security'},
                                    '_request_id' => 2009673841,
                                    '_index' => 48,
                                    '_leading_dot' => 1,
                                    '_buffer' => '0.communityname�!w�0q0+C�S�f',
                                    '_timeout_id' => [],
                                    '_callback' => undef,
                                    '_transport' => $VAR1->{'_transport'},
                                    '_length' => 48,
                                    '_error_index' => 0,
                                    '_var_bind_types' => {
                                                           '.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0' => 67
                                                         },
                                    '_version' => 1,
                                    '_security_name' => 'community',
                                    '_var_bind_list' => {
                                                          '.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0' => '255 days, 00:18:57.66'
                                                        },
                                    '_translate' => 255,
                                    '_error_status' => 0,
                                    '_scoped' => 0,
                                    '_var_bind_names' => [
                                                           '.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0'
                                                         ],
                                    '_error' => undef,
                                    '_pdu_type' => 162
                                  }, 'Net::SNMP::PDU' )
               }, 'Net::SNMP' );
```

Now.. the culprit with the failing host is that the SNMP community for it is different than for the other hosts -- however, even then, shouldn't the script already return the session error as it is failing to open the session to the host in question?

Comment: `if( !defined $session ) { .... $session->close(); }` - if `$session` is not defined you cannot call a method on it. Also, what exactly is the code in *"db.pl line 103"* ? It is impossible to say from what you provide as information.

Comment: Also:  1) the output `error:...`, `error:...`, and `debug:...` -- who prints that? Where does it come from? 2) You mark the line "_where Perl fails_" and that is after the `printf` with `[SESSION ERROR] ...` -- does that `printf` really not print, so `$session` is defined?  Can you then test how valid `$session` is in some other (controlled) way?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it's the same script, i just changed the filename for obfuscation.
If the session isn't getting defined, why is it not failing with `$session->error()` then?

Comment: @zdim everything, including the `error:...` lines are being output by the same script / file. That output is from the `-debug => DEBUG_ALL` toggle. The printf really does not print, so the `$session` isn't getting defined, which is why I am wondering why it is not failing with `$session->error()`.

Comment: Which line of code is script.pl line 103?

Comment: @Schwern this one, as written in the initial message/code block:
```my $snmp_response = $session->get_request( -varbindlist => [ ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0" ] )->{".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"};```

Comment: In fact, I tried adding an extra ```if..else``` loop right after that line, so that if the `get_request` fails, it would fail on error and only then proceed further. But that didn't help either, I still run into the same undefined value problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check the line where it is failing (shown with some added new lines for better reading):

```
my $snmp_response = 
    $session->get_request( -varbindlist => [ ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0" ] )
    ->{".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"};
```

This is basically the same as

```
my $result = $session->get_request( -varbindlist => [ ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0" ] );
my $snmp_response = $result->{".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"};
```

The problem is when the first line with `get_request` fails - because this will return undef. Then it will try to treat an undefined value as a hash reference - which is exactly the error you got.

The fix is not to ignore that `get_request` might fail. But check for it before using it as a hash.

Comment: A-ha! That was it. Thank you @SteffenUlrich !